# How to select clamping diodes

Tags: voltage, diodes, diode-clamp

I have a current sense amplifier (TI INA303, the 50V/V gain version) that I want to read with a microcontroller. I've looked all over the place trying to find how to select the proper clamping diodes that will make sure the output of this doesn't get too high and destroy my microcontroller.

What type of diodes do I need to use to protect my microcontroller from getting fried? It is a Microchip SAMC21 running at 3.3V. I've seen differing opinions on Zener vs Schottky, and have no clue what voltage the zeners/schottky diodes need to be rated at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *how to select the proper clamping diodes that will make sure the
> output of this doesn't get too high and destroy my microcontroller.*

Just look inside the red boxes I added to the schematic on page 1 of the data sheet and tell me why you think it might not be compatible without having to use diodes or zeners: -

[image]

Hint: the outputs cannot exceed the power rail (2.7 volt to 5.5 volt): -

[image]

Comment: I guess I don't really understand what "swing" means. If I put more current across the resistor than calculated, then will the voltage just sit at the supply voltage?

Comment: It will clamp or limit to the supply voltage \$V_S\$. You don't need to worry if you make the supply 3.3 volts or less.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Andy's answer:

[image]

[image]

See notes (2) and (3), you may need to protect the inputs by adding a series resistors (RC filter) to limit the input current below 5mA.

[image]

Comment: My working voltages are nominally 15V, maximum 24V, so I don't think I need the extra parts. I'm using this chip to detect very small pulses in current (think 10mA) running at 250,000 bits per second, so extra parts like an RC filter could mess things up

Comment: @DavidCutting If there are inductors, motors involved then several hundreds volts is not an unusual spike.